# Cannot listen for keypress inside section

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a program which key is pressed after the user clicked on a section of the webpage (I do not want anything to happen if the user has selected another section sort of like how keyboard shortcuts on windows only work when you have a specific window selected). I am currently trying to do this by this method:

```
const body = document.querySelector('#main-section')
body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
console.log(e.code)
})
```

This however is not working and there isn't an error in the console either. I have searched through the MDN documentation for addEventListener but I cannot find anything related to this problem.
Here is the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IDK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
    <script src="/public/js/main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="main-section">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you press a key inside the section and not outside of it?

Comment: I want it to be sort of like how keyboard shortcuts only work when you have selected a specific window. I have edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: But you didn't focus the section in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add attribute `tabindex="-1"` to the section tag to make it focusable

```js
const body = document.querySelector('#main-section')
body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  console.log(e.code)
})
```

```html
<section tabindex="-1" id="main-section">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Negative values makes things not focusable, you meant positive value

Comment: >> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1" ) means that the element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but could be focused with JavaScript or visually by clicking with the mouse

Comment: Could be, but it doesn't make it focusable by mouse

Comment: It makes. Just try it by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, you were right